# Trying to recreate this template, but the menu is not working as I want it to?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my menu look like the one on [this page](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/templates/Kelly/).

But somehow it's not working. This is [my website](http://mariafloscher.netlify.app/) so far. My main pet peeves with this is the menu items are not centered and the social media icons are nowhere to be seen.

Not only that, but even though I have the same thing written in every page (I copy-pasted everything), the home page is the only one that's listening to the CSS.

This is my code so far:

```css
body {
  background-color: #202020 !important;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

#header {
  background-color: #202020;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 2px 0px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background-color: #202020;
  height: fit-content;
}

.nav-link {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background-color: #202020;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #202020;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

.navbar a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f8f8f8;
}

.navbar-brand {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #202020;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header-social-links a {
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
  color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #f8f8f8;
  background-color: #202020;
}

#name {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar order-last order-lg-0">
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="name">Maria F. Loscher</a>
        <button class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="pages/about.html">about me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="pages/portfolio.html">portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="pages/cv.html">curriculum vitae</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="pages/commissions-hiring.html">commissions' pricing and hiring info</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="pages/about.html#contact">contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="header-social-links">
      <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>
```

Comment: This is a simple path issue. The path to your css file is https://mariafloscher.netlify.app/src/style.css. Your pages other than your home page are in a 'pages' subfolder. It is looking for the style in https://mariafloscher.netlify.app/pages/src/style.css (and the css file is not there).. that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Maria F. Loscher</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
<style>
.body {
    background-color: #202020 !important;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

#header {
    background-color: #202020;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px auto;
}

.navbar { 
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-link {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #202020;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color: #202020;
}

.navbar li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
}

.navbar a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f8f8f8;
}

.navbar-brand {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #202020;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.header-social-links a {
    line-height: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
    color: #f8f8f8;
    border-color:#f8f8f8;
    background-color: #202020;
}

#name {
    font-size: 20px;
}

</style>

<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
    <header id="header" class="fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar order-last order-lg-0">
            <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="name">Maria F. Loscher</a>
                        <button class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" 
                            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="pages/about.html">about me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="pages/portfolio.html">portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="pages/cv.html">curriculum vitae</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="pages/commissions-hiring.html">commissions' pricing and hiring info</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="pages/about.html#contact">contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="header-social-links">
            <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

1. I throw your navbar in the same div as the navitems
2. I added some css code for the navbar from here:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp